# How to extract cell data for a specific column with xpath?

Tags: web-scraping, xpath

So I've been looking for a solution to this, and while I've found some answers none of them seem to work. The table I'm attempting to extract data from looks like so:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped" style="color:#fff; ">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col"><div style="width:100%;">#</div></th>
    <th scope="col" sort="outfit_name"><div style="width:100%;min-width:150px" class="btn btn-primary" sort="name" onclick="reorder('1')">1</div></th>
    <th scope="col" sort="price"><div style="width:100%;" class="btn btn-primary" sort="rarity" onclick="reorder('rarity')">2</div></th>
    <th scope="col" sort="text"><div style="width:100%;min-width:50px" class="btn btn-primary" sort="outfitType" onclick="reorder('2')">3</div></th>
    <th scope="col" sort="text"><div style="width:100%;min-width:50px" class="btn btn-primary" sort="craftable" onclick="reorder('3')">4</div></th>
    <th scope="col" sort="text"><div style="width:100%;min-width:50px" class="btn btn-primary" sort="locationText" onclick="reorder('4')">5</div></th>
    <th scope="col" sort="instructions"><div style="width:100%;" class="btn btn-primary" sort="vendorText" onclick="reorder('5')">6</div></th>
    <th scope="col" sort="outfit_class"><div style="width:100%;" class="btn btn-primary" sort="themeText" onclick="reorder('6')">7</div></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px; vertical-align: middle;">1</th>
    <td style="font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle;">info here</td>
    <td style="font-size: 13px; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;">info here</td>
    <td style="font-size: 13px; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;">info here</td>
    <td style="font-size: 13px; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;"> info here </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><div style="width:85px;" onclick="load_vendor(this)" context="<p>data here</p>" outfit="Name Here" class="btn btn-primary"> ️</div></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><div style="width:93px;" onclick="load_theme(this)" context="<p>data here</p>" outfit="Name Here" class="btn btn-primary"> ℹ️ </div></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

In this example, how would I select cells for the 6th column? Another caveat to this is that not all cells have info in them. Ive tried using

```
//td[position()<=(count(//tr/th[.='6']/preceding-sibling::*)+1)]
```

however this doesn't seem to work. Lastly, I'm attempting to use this xpath for data extraction using Octoparse. Literally nothing I try works, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `before 6th column` in stead of `for the 6th column`

Answer (score -1):

`position()<=<NUMBER>` means that you want to select all the cells with index *less or equal to `<NUMBER>`*. Did you mean

```
//td[position()=(count(//tr/th[.='6']/preceding-sibling::*)+1)]
```

?